# To get focus back after postback. ASP.Net MVC 2 Web application using multiple html forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, xhtml, c#-4.0, webforms, textinput

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 application in C#. I have two HTML forms on my content page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
<form id="form1">
<input id="text1" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input id="text2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

What I want to do is to set the focus to Text Box after post back. After "form1" is submitted, "text1" should have focus and similarly after "form2" is submitted, "text2" should have the focus so that the user doesn't have to use mouse to put the focus back in text box and continue typing.

The following code works fine for a single HTML form on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
void function setfocus() {
    document.getElementById("text1").focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setfocus();">
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<input id="text1" type="text">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*The problem is I have two HTML forms on the page. Another issue is my web forms are on the content page of asp.net master page which reside inside the  and only master form has  tag which has "onload" property.

A friend of mine suggested me to use Ajax's ScriptManager and UpdatePannel. However, the UpdatePannel doesn't like HTML's  elements inside it. It seems only support asp.net control elements.

Very grateful for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <form id="form1">
        <input id="text1" type="text" />
        <input name="selectedTextBox" type="hidden" value="text1" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
        <input id="text2" type="text" />
        <input name="selectedTextBox" type="hidden" value="text2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    var textBoxID = "<%: Context.Request.Form["selectedTextBox"] %>";
    void function setfocus() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById(textBoxID);
        if(textBox) textBox.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Prefix Context to Request object

Comment: Hi Cybernate. Thank you for your prompt reply. My question is where and on which event we should call javascript function "setfocus()" on ASP .Net content page? Calling that function from Form's "onsubmit()" event will not work. I tried to get "textBoxID" value by "alert(textBoxID);" and call the "setfocus()" function from form's "onsubmit()"event, it returns empty string.

Comment: Hi Cybernate, your solution worked finally. The thing is we are missing Context. When I try Context.Request.Form["selectedTextBox"], it worked. Yayyyy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thx JOnas, didn;t notice tht. Updated the answer to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could append a hash to the `action` attribute of the first form:

```
<form id="form1" action="#form1">
    <input id="text1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input id="text2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and then test for the presence of this hash in the url:

```
function setfocus() {
    if (document.location.hash.indexOf('#form1') > -1) {
        // form1 was submitted => set focus to the second textbox
        document.getElementById("text2").focus();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text1").focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thank you for your solution. My question is on which event should I call "setfocus()" function to make sure the text box has focus after postback?

Comment: @Jonas, you could call it on the `onload` event which is fired when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Hi Darin, thank you for you reply. First part is solved. I got focus on "text1" on page load. After I posted "form1", it lost focus and it doesn't go either "text1" or "text2" but when I posted "form2", its focus goes back to "text2". The solution I am looking for is "form1 was submitted => set focus to the "text1" textbox" and "form2 was submitted => set focus to the "text2" textbox". I think we are on the right track. Any idea?